# Вертикальное центрирование блока

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css3

Нужно выровнять блок по центру по вертикали, важно `.bloc` = `position:relative;`

```css
.bloc {
  height: 500px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #14E051;
}
#center {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #E75415;
}
```

```html
<div class="bloc">
  <div id="center">2345678901234567</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот хороший пример, может тебе подойдет.

```css
.bloc {
  background-color: #14E051;
  height: 500px;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
#center {
  background-color: #E75415;
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bloc">
  <div id="center">2345678901234567</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

С помощью display: table-cell:

```
   .bloc {
      height: 500px;
      width: 150px;
      background-color: #14E051;
      display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #center {
      height: 100px;
      width: 150px;
      background-color: #E75415;
    }
```

Еще способ c position: absolute:

```
.bloc {
     height: 500px;
     width: 150px;
     background-color: #14E051;
    }

    #center {
     height: 100px;
     width: 150px;
     background-color: #E75415;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     margin-top: -50px;
    }
```

Альтернативное решение. В этому случае ширину для #center задать не получится.

```
.bloc {
     height: 500px;
     width: 150px;
     background-color: #14E051;
}
#center {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: middle;
     background-color: #E75415;
     height: 100px;
}
.bloc:before {
     content: "";
     display: inline-block;
     min-height: inherit;
     height: 100%;
     vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.vert_style{
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:middle;
}
.vert_style:last-child{
 width:0;
 height:100%;
}

<div class="bloc">
 <div id="center" class="vert_style"> 2345678901234567 </div><div class="vert_style"></div>
</div>
```

главное чтобы закрывающий тег vert_style и следущий за ним был без пробела и переноса строки

Answer (score 0):

Для меня это работает в большинстве случаев. After вместо Before спасает от переноса размером со всю высоту блока.

```
.bloc {
  height: 500px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #14E051;
}
.bloc:after {
  content: ' ';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}
#center {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #E75415;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cпособ c использованием transform: translate

```css
.bloc {
    height: 500px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #14E051;
    position: relative;
}
#center {
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #E75415;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bloc">
    <div id="center">2345678901234567</div>
</div>
```

Способ с использованием `display: flex` + `align-items: center`

```css
.bloc {
    height: 500px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #14E051;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#center {
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #E75415;  
}
```

```html
<div class="bloc">
    <div id="center">2345678901234567</div>
</div>
```